# INSERT INTO With a SubQuery and some operations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to insert some data to a table contains two things : "a string" and "maximum number in `Order` column + 1".

This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ([Text],[Order]) 
SELECT 'MyText' , (Max([Order]) + 1) 
FROM MyTable
```

What is going wrong with my query?

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2005 SP3.

Comment: @subt13 Microsoft SQL Server 2005 SP3

Comment: you don't need a LIMIT.. if you want to have additional Criteria add a WHERE CLAUSE

Comment: @BrianHoover probably something like `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near '1'.` because LIMIT 1 isn't valid on SQL Server

Comment: @DJKRAZE Yes. I don't need it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test this query like this:

I don't receive error:

```
create table #MyTable
(
    [Text] varchar(40),
    [Order] int NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO #MyTable([Text],[Order]) 
SELECT 'MyText' [Text], isnull(max([order]) + 1, 0) [Order] 
FROM #MyTable

drop table #MyTable
```

Original:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ([Text],[Order]) 
SELECT 'MyText' [Text], max([Order]) + 1 [Order] 
FROM MyTable
```

or

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ([Text],[Order]) 
SELECT top 1 'MyText' [Text], max([Order]) + 1 [Order] 
FROM MyTable
```

limit is not valid in SQL Server as far as I know.

Comment: Well, in your question you posted a table called MyTable and a definition for which this error would (potentially) not occur

Comment: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Order', table 'master.dbo.MyTable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: I've updated my solution.  Please try the sample code to see if you still receive error.

Comment: But i'm giving error with this query : INSERT INTO MyTable(Text, [OrderBy]) SELECT 'MyText' [Text], MAX([Order]) + 1 [Order] FROM MyTable

Comment: do not use that Insert query use the one this on INSERT INTO MyTable ([Text],[Order]) SELECT 'MyText' , (isnull(Max([Order]),0) + 1) FROM MyTable just like @Christian suggested.

Comment: If you do not allow nulls (NOT NULL) and your table is empty  you will receive this error.  You can use isnull() to avoid this.  I'll update the answer

Comment: subt13 you may want to also recommend a basic SQL site for the OP as well.. awesome Edit by the way.. as frustrating as this one question has become.. +2 to you

Comment: @DJKRAZE -  I recommend he spend lots of time on MSDN and to get used to their documentation.  (e.g. for isnull: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

Comment: I agree... it will truly help him in the long run especially if he decides to incorporate SQL into something like Java, jscript, or C#..ect

Answer (score 3):

Unless he has a column named OrderBy

then he would have to add / assign all values within that Insert especially if the column does not allow for nulls
sounds like fully qualifying the Insert with the dbo.MyTable.Field may make more sense.
also why are you naming fields with SQL Key words...???

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ([Text],[Order] Values('MyTextTest',1)
```

try a test insert first..

Comment: Sorry for my bad comment. I have deleted it. The error is "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Order', table 'master.dbo.MyTable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated."

Comment: I think I'm getting this error because Max() function returns nothing since my table is currently empty (has no rows)

Answer (score 3):

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Order', table 'master.dbo.MyTable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

This means that the `Order` column isn't allowed to be null, **and** that the `Max([Order]) + 1` part of your column returns NULL.
This is because your table is empty, as you already noticed by yourself.

You can work around this by replacing NULL by a real number in the query, using [`ISNULL()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ([Text],[Order]) 
SELECT 'MyText' , (isnull(Max([Order]),0) + 1) 
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: I hate to be the one to say.. but it's like he doesn't realize from the get that he's inserting nothing into his table I can understand if he were Inserting into MyTest and the Select table were something like dbo.YourTest .. initial query doesn't even add up to what he is trying to do..